# Android BOOT_COMPLETE Receiver not working on CN1

Tags: codenameone

I wonder if this is a CN1-specific thing or if it is related to Galaxy A6. My intuition tells me that the context in this receiver and the context in `com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity().getApplicationContext()` aren't the same

I am adding the below

In `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` build hint: `true`

In `android.xapplication` build hint:

```
<receiver android:name="com.groups.AutoStartReceiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then, for a receiver placed in native/android (where I write something into a test file to verify it has been called):

```
package com.groups;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) 
{
    DataOutputStream os = null;
  try {
      os = new DataOutputStream(context.openFileOutput("testLogger", 0));
      os.writeUTF("onReceive called");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  } finally {
      try {
          os.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
      }
  }
}
}
```

However, when I read the content of the text file after booting and starting the app the file isn't found (FileNotFoundException)

I have checked the code that writes into the file separately (while app is running) and it works. I know I could use Preferences but I'm trying to keep it as native as possible in case Preferences isn't liked by the OS at boot time etc

I can share my entire Manifest file if needed

Comment: If you use the notifications package the receive boot completed permission is added implicitly. I suggest downloading the Android native sources for the app and trying to track this using Android Studio and logging in the native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that BOOT_COMPLETED has been deprecated and no longer works. I've read this in a few places but nowhere official